# Synchronisation in OpenGL (part 1.1)

Tags: opengl, synchronization, glsl, shader

My questions pertain to the use of a single OpenGL 4.5 context without any direct memory mapping or explicit synchronisation (hypothetically), with both rendering shaders (invoked with `glDrawArrays()`) and compute shaders (invoked with `glDispatchCompute()`).

**Question 1.1:** Are all changes to rendering state – such as with `glUseProgram()`, `glEnable()`/`glDisable()`, `glStencilFunc()`, `glStencilOp()`,`glClearColor()`, `glStencilMask()`, `glClearStencil()`, `glBlendFunc()`, `glColorMask()`, etc.  – made by the client application BEFORE invoking shaders guaranteed to be seen by those shader invocations (and associated fixed-function rendering operations)?

And if the answer is **NO**, what forms of synchronisation when added would change the answer to **YES**?